# Disabling some code completely in standard c++?

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae

Trying to understand what the best way to disable code parts currently is with all the fancy features we have in C++ nowadays.

My test implementations are as follows.

1) Using `static if` (c++17 and newer):

```
inline constexpr bool LogEnabled = false; // this would come from, say, Makefile

struct logger
{
    static logger &instance()
    {
        static logger lg;
        return lg;
    }

    inline void log(std::string_view msg)
    {
        if constexpr (LogEnabled)
        {
            cout << msg << endl;
        }
    }
};
```

2) Using `template specialization` (fine for c++98 i believe):

```
inline constexpr bool LogEnabled = false; 

struct logger
{
    static logger &instance()
    {
        static logger lg;
        return lg;
    }

    template <bool Enable = LogEnabled>
    inline void log(std::string_view msg)
    {
        // nop version
    }

    template <>
    inline void log<true>(std::string_view msg)
    {
        cout << msg << endl;
    }
};
```

3) I had an idea to use `SFINAE` with `std::enable_if` but could not quite get it to work.

Here is the call site requirement:

```
int main()
{
    logger::instance().log("bruh");
    return 0;
}
```

So what happens if you compile both versions with `-O3 -std=c++17` is that the optimizer completely removes generated code for the whole log line in main leaving main look like this:

```
main:                                   # @main
    xor     eax, eax
    ret
```

This is great. Both versions do exactly what we want and completely remove the code. But this only happens if the optimization flag is used. If we have `-O0` then the call to logger remains even tho it's a `nop` in both cases.

Is there a better way to do this in clean C++ (please no preprocessor from all the way back to the 90s). Something that would not need the optimizer to do work. Maybe SFINAE could do that better? Can anyone please show an example of a SFINAE version of this?

Thank you!

Comment: `if constexpr` is no better than a regular `if` when used outside of a template, or when the condition doesn't depend on a template parameter.

Comment: Question 2 is just asking for close votes as opinion-based...

Comment: "*please no preprocessor from all the way back to the 90s*" Why not?

Comment: `inline` is completely redundant here (except on the variable definition). Member functions defined inside the class definition are `inline` by default.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat trying to understand what you mean. The compile-time LogEnabled boolean is set from the command line like -DENABLE_LOG=0 and then applied via #ifdef. For the sake of clarity and readability this was omitted. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @walnut That's good to know. Thanks. I tried to see what asm is generated with or without inline there and it generates the same assembly so you are totally right here.

Comment: @NicolBolas the less remains of C the better. Just my preference I guess.

Comment: @AlexKremer Both GCC and Clang optimize out the branch (even if it is just a regular `if`) even with `-O0`: https://godbolt.org/z/xHRcP8 You cannot force the compiler to inline a function call (especially without optimizations enabled), so you can never avoid that as long as you are using a regular function call for `log` in `main`. Optimizing code, but targeting the `-O0` optimization level is also pointless. The code generated by `-O0` will never perform well.

Comment: @walnut wow this is very cool. I didn't realise that it was enough for LogEnabled to be marked constexpr for a regular if to work just as well as static if. Thanks for that.

Comment: @walnut as for ```-O0``` it's a thought experiment, not a requirement. I'm just trying to figure out if there is a way in c++ to achieve what i want without any optimization requirement. Obviously it's not aimed at production or anything.

Comment: Contrary to C# which has an attribute for that purpose, in general, you cannot be sure that every code is removed if there is a function or user conversion at call site (for ex. `GetTheTextToLog()`) and thus the only solution that works in all cases is using macros.

Comment: On a small side-note: You don't need conditional compilation with `#ifdef` to set the value of `LogEnabled`, just initialize it to a macro set on the command line.